# Can I use my iPhone as a fax machine modem using the Bluetooth connection?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, fax

I'd like to use my iPhone 4 as a bluetooth modem so I can send a fax using my Mac.

I can pair my iPhone to the mac and then add a fax from the Printer section of System Preferences and then, I can add to the Fax print queue from Preview. However, the print queue doesn't establish a connection to the iPhone.

I'm not interested in sending faxes over email and I'm not interested in downloading an app to the iPhone that will send faxes over the internet. I'm interested in using my iPhone as my fax machine modem and printing from my Mac.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a solution to do this about a week ago, and found that if you're in the US with a non-jailbroken phone, you just can't.

Yeah, it annoyed me, too.

There are a number of different Bluetooth profiles; here's Apple's list of [Supported Bluetooth profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647). No faxing on there, dammit.